# The Virtue of Woman

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

Please explain this Frederick Von Schiller poem:

"Man of virtue has need;-into life with boldness he plunges,
 Entering with fortune more sure into the hazardous strife;
But to woman one virtue suffices; it is ever shining
 Lovingly forth to the heart; so let it shine to the eye!"

Comment: Please pose a specific question about English language and usage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a  v e r y  b a d  translation of a German epigram.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within scope.

Answer (score 1):

The poem is a simple contrast of man's need to face life with its dangers and mutability, with  a woman's need to preserve herself as an ideal for the man who struggles.  The virtue would be virginity until marriage and a loving fidelity thereafter.

"Man of virtue has need"--suggests that it is almost a biological requirement for a man to entangle himself in temporal events (including warfare and politics).  By contrast a woman is required to preserve herself unsullied in any way as an almost mystical ideal which provides him comfort.

In other words, "virtue" for a man differs from that for a woman.  A virtuous man entangles himself in the world while a virtuous woman protects an essential part of herself to the point she becomes nearly a goddess.